# How to read from multiple input (text) files at the same time and print it again after doing some calculation?

Tags: python, text-files

I have two inputs from two different dictionaries (separate txt file), I want to read both files line by line, compare and print the result in a txt file. (in a loop) 
my two inputs look like this

```
eshark 
white 
shark
shark
carcharodon
carcharias
```

and

```
etench
tinca 
goldfish 
carassius 
auratus
great
```

I tried

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1: # for the first file 
data = f1.read()

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f2:
data1 = f2.read() 
output = data == data1   # output is 1(true) or 0 (false)    
with open("Output1.txt", "w") as text_file 
text_file.write("word: %s :%s :%f" % (data ,data1 , output ))
```

I tried this as well, but same problem

`with open('file1.txt') as f1,open('file2.txt') as f2:`

I got the right output when my data come from one file but, when I tried with both files, I got this output:

```
word:shark 
white 
shark
shark
carcharodon
carcharias
:shark
```

Meanwhile, I want this output

```
word:etench : 0
word:white : tinca : 0
word:shark : goldfish  : 0 
word:shark : carassius : 0 
word:carcharodon : auratus : 0
word:carcharias : great : 0
```

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is may be an answer to your question:

```
with open("file1", 'r') as f1, open("file2", 'r') as f2:
    j= 0
    data2 = [k.strip("\n").strip() for k in f2.readlines()]
    for line in f1:
        if j == len(data2):
            break
        if line.strip("\n").strip() == data2[j:j+1][0]:
            output = "word:{0}:{1} = {2}".format(line.strip("\n").strip(), data2[j:j+1][0], 1)
        else:
            output = "word:{0}:{1} = {2}".format(line.strip("\n").strip(), data2[j:j+1][0], 0)
        j += 1

        with open("output_file", 'a') as out:
            out.write(output + "\n")
```

Output:

```
word:eshark:etench = 0
word:white:tinca = 0
word:shark:goldfish = 0
word:shark:carassius = 0
word:carcharodon:auratus = 0
word:carcharias:great = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use readlines to read the files into lists and then iterate to compare:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    data1 = f.readlines()
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    data2 = f.readlines()
data = zip(data1, data2)
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    for x in data:
        out = '{} : {} : {}\n'.format(x[0].strip(), x[1].strip(), x[0] == x[1])
        f.write(out)
```

Comment: If you move the context manager outside of the `for` loop you avoid having to open and close the file each time you pass through the loop.

Comment: @Batman sound argument, edited accordingly, thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there. Once you've read the data in though you need to iterate over each line. At the moment you're not. You can do that by using `zip` to pair the lines from the different files together.

Personally I'd use generators (because I love generators), but it's not necessary.

```
def read_lines(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            yield line

data1 = read_lines(r"/Documents/file1.txt")
data2 = read_lines(r"/Documents/file2.txt")
data = zip(data1, data2)

with open(r"/Documents/output.txt", 'w') as fh:
    for left, right in data:
        equal = left == right
        line = "word:{left}: {right}: {equal}\n".format(left=left.strip(), 
                                                        right=right.strip(), 
                                                        equal=equal)
        fh.write(line)
```